# CMake generate config.h like from Autoconf

Tags: cmake, autotools

When using the Autotools it's common to generate a `config.h` file by specifying the `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` macro in `configure.ac` like this:

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
```

What is the respective equivalent for this when using CMake?

Comment: See [specific](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) and
[general](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks) documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How to check header files and library functions like in Autotools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647892/cmake-how-to-check-header-files-and-library-functions-like-in-autotools)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to create a file similar to `config.h.in`. Something like

```
#cmakedefine HAVE_FEATURE_A @Feature_A_FOUND@
#cmakedefine HAVE_FEATURE_B @Feature_B_FOUND@
#cmakedefine HAVE_FEATURE_BITS @B_BITSIZE@
```

Then you have to declare the variables `Feature_A_FOUND`, `Feature_B_FOUND`, `B_BITSIZE` in your CMake code and call

```
configure_file(config.h.in config.h)
```

which will result in a config.h file similar to the one from the autotools. If a variable is not found or is set to false, the line will be commented. Otherwise the value will be inserted. Assume `Feature_A_FOUND=A-NOTFOUND`¸ `Feature_B_FOUND=/usr/lib/b`, `B_BITSIZE=64`, which will result in

```
/* #undef HAVE_FEATURE_A @Feature_A_FOUND@ */
#define HAVE_FEATURE_B /usr/lib/b
#define HAVE_FEATURE_BITS 64
```

Probably HAVE_FEATURE_B would be better defined as `#cmakedefine01` which results in 0 or 1 depending on the value of the variable.

In general it is possible to create every config.h file generated by Autotools as CMake is more flexible. But it requires more work and you cannot automatically get a config.h, but you have to write the .in file yourself.

Documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/configure_file.html

Comment: `#cmakedefine` works only if both identifier and value match i.e. `#cmakedefine MY_VAR @MY_VAR@` works as expected, but `#cmakedefine ABC @MY_VAR@` led to `/* #undef ABC */`, since only `MY_VAR` was a variable (`ABC` wasn't).  Doing `#define ABC @MY_VAR@` worked instead. Great answer though; helped me. Thanks!