# How I can find out if a Linux system uses Wayland or X11?

Tags: c++, linux, c++14, x11, wayland

### Used language

I am using C++14 with cmake for my program.

### Problem:

I would like to know how I can find out if a Linux system uses Wayland or X11 as a window system to be able to use both APIs in my source code without conflict.
Thus creating a window with Wayland when Wayland is available and otherwise use 
the X11 API.

Note: I know there is XWayland, but I want to use native X11 and native Wayland without something like XWayland.

**EDIT:** To clarify some things: I *don't* want to check for X11 or Wayland *at compile-time*, but **instead at runtime**, because then I just have to compile the code once and it doesn't require the user to think about which version to use.

Comment: What's the use case? For your average Linux desktop application, you don't need to know this -- you write it with a high level toolkit (Qt, GTK+, Wx, etc.) and that toolkit takes care of the X11/Wayland support for you.

Comment: I want to develope a software which renderes direclty to the window screen using OpenGL. The software itself doesn't really rely on knowing a lot of things I am doing, but I want to create the technical backend of the software myself, thus I have to know how to do such things.

Comment: @shadowdragon every self respecting windowing toolkit allows you to render your opengl to its windows. No need to write your own for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effective way of detecting X11 vs Wayland, preferrably with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135228/effective-way-of-detecting-x11-vs-wayland-preferrably-with-cmake)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicated question as I don't want to detect the used window system at compile-time, but instead at runtime.

Comment: One motivation for Wayland is getting rid of cruft needed to implement the X protocol; no surprise to me Wayland attracts developers who are interested in minimalism and want to avoid dependencies - or just learn about the next lower layer. When doing DRM coding, I found the "low level" userspace libraries useful as sample code (along with the kernel source), but I didn't use them. Abstraction is powerful in SW development, but sometimes it presents an interface that's as ill-suited to purpose, or worse, than the one it abstracts away.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

X11 uses the `DISPLAY` environment variable to find the X server. Wayland uses `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`. Look for the Wayland variable first. Then if you don't find it or you can't connect go on to using X11.

Do not skip checking the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable or assume Wayland is running on "wayland-0". Some people want to use nested compositors, which you would bypass. Other people may be running Wayland but want to force X11 rendering by deleting the WAYLAND_DISPLAY variable.

Comment: You explained in a comment earlier that the `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` may not always be set. Could you explain why it isn't always set to the correct window system and why the `DISPLAY` variable is? I am also wondering what the `localhost:10.0` is for. As far as my understanding goes, it has something to do with the X window system, but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ShadowDragon: The XDG variables are not set because I'm not in a desktop session. I'm coming in remotely using SSH tunneling. SSH can provide an X11 proxy, and it puts the proxy address at `localhost:10.0`

Answer (score 19):

use the environment variable `XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

on x11

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

on wayland

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

Comment: That isn't what I'd call reliable.

Comment: For example, I'm logged in to my Linux system using PuTTY on Windows and my X11 `DISPLAY` is set to `localhost:10.0`. It works just fine with XMing running. But `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is not set to anything. I don't have any XDG variables of any kind set.

Comment: This doesn't work, sometimes you get "tty" which doesn't help matters.

Comment: Incorrect! You will get "tty" when using either if you don't use a display manager.